# sharing common functionality for template functions when the template changes a small portion

Tags: c++, templates

My project has a couple of awkward locations with respect to templates.  I understand that my usage is slightly non-standard, but the awkwardness as fundamental benefits (primarily, unrolling a bunch of loops).  AKA please do not respond with "oh you shouldn't be using templates".  The awkwardness involved has empirically been shown to have over a 10x speedup...

The templates below use `enum class SomeThing : uint8_t`.  There is a

```
template <SomeThing ST>
struct projection_functor {
    static constexpr unsigned WIDTH  = 640u;/// *** only in
    static constexpr unsigned HEIGHT = 480u;/// *** specializations...
    void toXYZ(...);
    ...
};
```

It is a guarantee that every possible value of `enum class SomeThing` has a specialized version.  Furthermore, the un-specialized version does not actually provide `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT`, only the specializations do (this is a compile-time assurance measure on my part).

What I would like to do is define a function using these closures:

```
template <SomeThing ST>
void forEachXYZ(...params...) {
    if(ST == SomeThing::FIRST)
        using proj = projection_functor<SomeThing::FIRST>;
    else if(ST == SomeThing::SECOND)
        using proj = projection_functor<SomeThing::SECOND>;
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported...");

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < proj::WIDTH * proj::HEIGHT; ++i) {
        // ... setup ...
        proj pf;
        pf.toXYZ(...);
    }
}
```

This does not compile, though, the problem being `proj` is not officially defined in every case I guess.  This is a really ugly but functional solution, that I would like to just keep in the `forEachXYZ`:

```
#define THIS_UGLY_MACRO() \
    for(unsigned int i = 0; n < proj::WIDTH * proj::HEIGHT; ++i) { \
        /* ... setup ... */ \
        proj pf; \
        pf.toXYZ(...); \
    }
```

And now I can call

```
template <SomeThing ST>
void forEachXYZ(...params...) {
    if(ST == SomeThing::FIRST) {
        using proj = projection_functor<SomeThing::FIRST>;
        THIS_UGLY_MACRO();
    }
    else if(ST == SomeThing::SECOND) {
        using proj = projection_functor<SomeThing::SECOND>;
        THIS_UGLY_MACRO();
    }
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported...");
}
```

Which apparently works because it is scoped to the `if` statements that are evaluated from the template parameter comparison.

Is this the only solution, or is there a better way to be able to inform the loop of what `proj` actually is, dependent upon the template parameter?

I suppose writing a helper function could be done, but this is more a higher level "what can I actually do with templates in this fashion" question.

Thank you for any advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a template instead of a macro:

```
template <class Projection>
void projectXYZ(...params...) {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; n < proj::WIDTH * proj::HEIGHT; ++i) {
        /* ... setup ... */
        Projection pf;
        pf.toXYZ(...);
    }
}
```

And then call it:

```
template <SomeThing ST>
void forEachXYZ(...params...) {
    if(ST == SomeThing::FIRST) {
        projectXYZ<projection_functor<SomeThing::FIRST>>(std::move(param), ...);
    }
    else if(ST == SomeThing::SECOND) {
        projectXYZ<projection_functor<SomeThing::SECOND>>(std::move(param), ...);
    }
    else {
        throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported...");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is DEFINITELY a lot cleaner.  Why is the `std::move` being used on the parameters? *Edit*: is this only for primitive types?  I did not include in the original description the fact that the `... params ...` were actually const references to classes / `std::vector`s etc, in which case `std::move` won't work.

However, it appears that using `std::move` here is an important concept.  Is this just an added optimization to 'forward' the arguments or something?

Comment: For const references std::move does nothing so it is usually omitted. But for movable types it will force compiler to use move constructor which can have less overhead then copy constructor.

Comment: Excellent, I'll make sure to remember that.  Thanks again for showing me the light, the macro solution felt so dirty, but I didn't connect to make a template function on the projection functor itself, rather than the `SomeThing`.